# Convert float into String and send from C code to Python through Named Pipe

Tags: python, c, linux, named-pipes

I would like to send float values from C code into Python code using named pipes. I am printing the received values into terminal in the Python side, however along with the value itself, gibberish characters are also displayed.

**Pipe opening:**

```
void Init_FIFO(void)
{
    // FIFO file path
    char * bldc_fifo = "/tmp/bldc_fifo";

    // Creating the named FIFO -- mkfifo(<pathname>, <permission>)
    mkfifo(bldc_fifo, 0666);

    // Open FIFO to write/read data
    fd_fifo = open(bldc_fifo, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    //fd_fifo = open(bldc_fifo, O_WRONLY | O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
}
```

**For the conversion of float to string I use sprintf and the code is given below,**

```
void SendDataOverFifo(float angle)
{
    char str[64];
    unsigned char writeBuffer[] = "Hello!";

    Init_FIFO();

    sprintf(str, "%f\n", angle);
    write(fd_fifo, str, sizeof(str));
    //write(fd_fifo, writeBuffer, sizeof(writeBuffer));
    close(fd_fifo);
}
```

**Then for receiving the code in the Python side, I use this**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import errno
import time

FIFO = '/tmp/bldc_fifo'

try:
    os.mkfifo(FIFO)
except OSError as oe: 
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

print("Opening FIFO...")
with open(FIFO, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fifo:
    print("FIFO opened")
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        data = fifo.read()
        print(data)
```

***The output I am getting is something like this***

i-W ?UOeiEU11.417070

***Where the correct result should be:***

11.417070

**A note:** If I try to send only "Hello!", it works without any problems.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use exponential format like `sprintf(str, "%e\n", angle);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first red flag is in the [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output-Functions.html#Formatted-Output-Functions) call; it doesn't know how large your target buffer `str` is, so could overflow if you're not careful. With a single float and 64 bytes, that step should be fine.

However, you didn't store the return value, so at this point you don't know how large the formatted text is. Then you used `sizeof`, which tells you how large the buffer is, not how much data you just put into it. You could use a string-based function (since `sprintf` wrote a nul-terminated string), such as `strlen` (to measure the string) or `fputs` (to write the string to file).

A much easier shortcut might be to use `fprintf` in the first place, and not need to allocate a separate buffer (it likely uses one built into `FILE`) to store the formatted string.

It is possible, albeit not necessarily portable or safe, to convert between file descriptors (such as `write` and `close` use) and `FILE` (such as `fprintf` uses) using functions such as [`fdopen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Descriptors-and-Streams.html#Descriptors-and-Streams).

Comment: I think the I cannot make use of fprintf because I am using named pipes not a FILE

Comment: ... that's why the last paragraph explains you can wrap a file descriptor. You're in a Unix type system, everything is a file (a named pipe is just a slightly special file).

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
write(fd_fifo, str, sizeof(str));
```

is causing unintialized memory to be written to the fifo. You don't want to write the whole `str` buffer, only the size of the string you want to pass. And you can find that out by `snprintf` return value of by using `strlen(str)`.

```
int ret = sprintf(str, "%f", ...);
assert(ret > 0); // just to be safe
write(fd_fifo, str, ret);
```

Using `sprintf` is unsafe for you cause. Use `snprintf` to protect against stack overflow.

```
int ret = snprintf(str, sizeof(str), ....
// no changes
```

That way `sprintf` will never write more than `sizeof(str)` characters into the buffer.

However the best way is to not have a statically allocated buffer. You can use `fdopen`:

```
FILE *f = fdopen(fd_fifo, "w");
if (f == NULL) {
      // handle error
}
int ret = fprintf(f, "%f", ...);
if (ret < 0) {
      // handle error
}
fclose(f);
```

or get to know the size of buffer beforehand, call malloc, and snprintf again:

```
int ret = sprintf(NULL, "%f", ...);
assert(ret > 0);
char *str = malloc(ret * sizeof(char));
if (str == NULL) { 
      // handler error
}
ret = snprintf(str, "%f", ...);
write(fd_fifo, str, ret);
free(str);
```

Comment: `snprintf` returns the number of characters that would have been written, so if you really want to guard against buffer overruns, you must also check `ret <= sizeof str`. [`asprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Output.html), if available, allows to allocate a sufficient buffer in one call.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the solution was changing this line

`write(fd_fifo, str, sizeof(str));`

to

`write(fd_fifo, str, strlen(str));`

Comment: Which is one of about three solutions indicated by both me and Kamil.

Comment: @YannVernier sorry I did not realize the strlen suggestion you guys gave I was sleepy I guess, my bad...